# This PHP commenting system doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, post, comments

I'm making a commenting on a post system on my site, and the result is the most recent comment being replaced with the new one. I want all comments to stay, not just one.

```
<?php
$placement=290;
$comment=fgets($file);
while ($comment!="") {

    $placement=$placement+5;
    echo'<div style="left:10px; position:relative; top:'.$placement.'px; border:solid; right:10px; height:75px;">';
    $comment=fgets($file);
    echo "<p>".$comment."</p>";
    echo'</div>';
}

$placement2=$placement+5;

if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    echo'<form method="POST" action="">';
    echo'<input type="text" columns="10" maxlength="500" style="position:relative; left:50px; width:80%; height:50px; resize:none; top:'.$placement2.'px;" name="comment" placeholder="Leave a comment! (max 500 characters)" >';
}

if (isset($_POST['comment']) or isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {

        $file=fopen('Questions/question'.$_GET['qid'],"r");
        $name=fgets($file);
        $info=fgets($file);
        $user=fgets($file);
        $n=fgets($file);
        $number=1;

        while($number<$n) {
            $comment=fgets($file);
            define("comment".$number,$comment);
            echo $number;
            $number=$number+1;
        }

        define("comment".$number,$_POST['comment']);
        echo trim(constant("comment1"));

        $file=fopen('Questions/question'.$_GET['qid'],"w");
        fwrite($file,$name);
        fwrite($file,$info);
        fwrite($file,$user);
        fwrite($file,$n);
        $number2=1;
        while($number2<$number) {
            $number2=$number2+1;
            fwrite($file, constant("comment".$number2)."\n");
            echo constant("comment".$number2)."\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I know something's wrong, I just don't know what. Also, no errors.

Comment: You would make it a lot easier for yourself if you used a database for this.

Comment: With the free host I'm using, I am incapable of using SQL.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would make reading and more importantly DEBUGGING this code much easier

Comment: sqlite is just file as well so you could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in `w` mode, which is placing the pointer at the beginning of the file, and overwriting your contents.

Refer to the [PHP fopen() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more information.

You'd most likely want `a` or `a+` mode, like so:

```
$file=fopen('Questions/question'.$_GET['qid'],"a+");
```

**Note:** writing a file based directly on a $_GET variable is **bad practice**.  You need to sanitize that variable. (You should sanitize ALL user input).  In this case, the simplest form of sanitization would look like this:

```
// typecast to an integer
$question_id = (int)$_GET['qid'];
// then use the known integer value
$file = fopen('Questions/question' . $question_id,"a+");
```

**Lastly**, the commments on your question are correct: you would have a much more robust system, and an easier time coding, if you used a database.  PHP goes well with mysql, but be sure to use the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries - do not use the `mysql_` library: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Perhaps I didn't search well enough through the file opening types. Thank you.